# Hibernate persistence.xml Unmarshall exception

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, orm, persistence

I'm trying to config a hibernate database through persitence.xml file. I currently have the following persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/BlingBankDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister">false</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The database seems seems to connect to the postgres cluster but I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.RevisionTypeType does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract int[] sqlTypes()' of interface org.hibernate.usertype.UserType.
```

This is the complete stack trace:

```
! java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at pt.tecnico.sirs.databaseserver.repository.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory (HibernateUtil.java:29)
    at pt.tecnico.sirs.databaseserver.repository.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit> (HibernateUtil.java:10)
    at pt.tecnico.sirs.databaseserver.DatabaseServer.<init> (DatabaseServer.java:20)
    at pt.tecnico.sirs.databaseserver.DatabaseServer.main (DatabaseServer.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.RevisionTypeType does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract int[] sqlTypes()' of interface org.hibernate.usertype.UserType.
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.<init> (CustomType.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.register (BasicTypeRegistry.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$2.contributeType (MetadataBuildingProcess.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.TypeContributorImpl.contribute (TypeContributorImpl.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes (MetadataBuildingProcess.java:391)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete (MetadataBuildingProcess.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build (MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build (MetadataBuilderImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build (MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at pt.tecnico.sirs.databaseserver.repository.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory (HibernateUtil.java:23)
    at pt.tecnico.sirs.databaseserver.repository.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit> (HibernateUtil.java:10)
    at pt.tecnico.sirs.databaseserver.DatabaseServer.<init> (DatabaseServer.java:20)
    at pt.tecnico.sirs.databaseserver.DatabaseServer.main (DatabaseServer.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:840)
```

And despite me explicitly defining the hibernate.listeners to false, it seems to still have Envers integration set to true.
What am I doing wrong?

I checked out some of the documentation and read a lot of similar problems but I can't find the solution.

Comment: This type of error, caught at runtime, usually indicates a version difference between the libraries in the compile environment vs the deployment environment.  Make sure the versions are the same in both places.

Comment: Thank you, I think I might have found the problem. You were right, mismatch between the hibernate-envers version and everything else.